# I want to find some columns in my data maximum value is not 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have 254 rows x 474 columns DataFrame data.

I want to find the columns which column's maximum value is not 1. Most of column's maximum value is 1, but some of column's maximum value is not 1.

I use python 3.x environment.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv") # this is my data.
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please keep in mind that stackoverflow is not a code writting service and you should therefore always add what you have tried by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `:` for get all rows and [`DataFrame.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) for filter columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,2,1],
                   'b':[0,0,1],
                   'c':[3,2,1]})

df1 = df.loc[:, df.max() != 1]
print (df1)
   a  c
0  0  3
1  2  2
2  1  1
```

If need columns names only:

```
c = df.columns[df.max() != 1]
print (c)
Index(['a', 'c'], dtype='object')
```